# Removing an update from a Software Update Group deletes the Package

Tags: windows-update, system-center

I've run into this several times now.  I had hoped that it would be fixed in CU4 but it does not appear to be.  Here is my scenario:  I have a Software Update Group named

> Windows Server 2008 R2 Updates - 201503

The updates have been deployed into a Deployment Package named

> DP - Windows Server 2008 R2 - 201503

(I had been packaging them into yearly packages but you'll see why i don't do that anymore in a moment).  I have had some of these updates either expire or be superseded so I need to remove them from the Software Update Group.  To do this I am selecting them, going to Edit Membership then un-checking any groups they are in.

Now here is the part that makes me ... dissatisfied.  Once I do this if I check the content status of my Deployment Package it now says

> The source directory "\\SCSM_SERVER\Updates\Windows Server 2008 R2\2015\03\bb97ff2f-4eb4-48b0-bf0b-096ee3bcb89b" for package "AAA00098" does not exist" ...

Anyone know how I can get it to stop from deleting the entire deployment package when I remove a couple updates?  Or is there a better way of handling this scenario?

Comment: I'm going to try downloading the content yet again.  This time the folder hierarchy is going to be Windows Server 2008 R2\201503.  Last time when it deleted the content it deleted the 2015 folder and everything in it so a bunch of Deployment Packages need to be downloaded again.

Comment: Well it worked OK for a while.  Now suddenly a couple of the monthly sub-folders have gone missing.  Does anyone know what is causing the content to periodically get culled?